# Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT,subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I am new to IOS programming, and using xCode 6.1.  I have fixed one of these errors already in my code, but this one I'm having no luck with.  Here is the code that is failing:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class ElementLoad: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var id: String
    @NSManaged var desc: String
    @NSManaged var type: String
    @NSManaged var strength: String

    class func createInManagedObjectContext(moc: NSManagedObjectContext, id: String, desc: String, type: String, strength: String) -> ElementLoad {
        **let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Elements", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as ElementLoad**  <-- FAILING
        newItem.id = id
        newItem.desc = desc
        newItem.type = type
        newItem.strength = strength

        //println(newItem)
        return newItem
    }
}
```

The above is called from:

```
ElementLoad.createInManagedObjectContext(self.managedObjectContext!, id: "EL:I:S", desc: "Elephants", type: "I", strength: "S")
```

Within AppDelegate.swift, since it's a one time load of data into CoreData. th

Any pointers as to what my problem might be? The data does actually get loaded into CoreData. But I would like to clean this up.  Thanks.